# How to prevent nose from importing __init__.py files?

Tags: python, package, nose, nosetests

Can the [nose](http://somethingaboutorange.com/mrl/projects/nose/) testing framework be instructed to only run tests in `test_*.py` files?

In fact, doing `nosetests A` with the following directory structure:

```
A/
  test_A.py
  B/
    __init__.py
```

imports B, which I want to avoid.

The reason for this is that the B module starts with `import numpy` because it is only meant to be used when the user has the optional NumPy module installed.  However, users who did not install NumPy do not want nosetests to process `B/__init__.py`, because it necessarily fails on `import numpy` even though NumPy is optional.  How can this be achieved?

Comment: Maybe you can move the optional code out of B/__init__.py into an B/numpy_support.py module.

Comment: @Adi: Yeah, but `import A.B` is the logical choice in my case (it is equal to `uncertainties.unumpy`, which contains replacement functions for `numpy` functions: it would be strange to call the replacement module `uncertainties.unumpy.numpy_support`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nose can accept/reject tests at the directory, file, module, class and method levels.  You need to reject the `B` **directory**.  There is no way to ignore the `__init__.py` file; Python never sees it.  It shows up when `B` is imported, so you need to ignore `B`.

Try:

```
nosetests --exclude=B
```

Comment: Note that this is an effect of the way that Python import stuff, it has nothing to do with Nose.

Comment: To make this answer more complete: the path in `--exclude=` is *relative* to the path given to nosetests. To continue the example in the question: `nosetests --exclude=B A/` (and not `--exclude=A/B`).

Answer (score 4):

Simply wrap the import with a `try:..except ImportError:...` block. In that case you could even set a variable letting you know if numpy is available or not.

Comment: I would like it if nose would allowed me to avoid this: the only reason why users use the B module is if they have NumPy installed, so the ability to run nose would be the only reason for an ImportError test.  I would like to avoid adding code in B that only makes sense for nose.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, just use the --match and the --exclude command line options to limit what nose will discover as a test program.

Comment: How do you use `--match` in this case?  Doing `nosetests --match 'X_*.py' A` still imports `B/__init__.py` even if there is no `X_*.py` file in `A`.

Comment: I also tried `nosetests --exclude '__init__.py' A`, but this still imports `B/__init__.py`.

Comment: I think that nose will still scan/import all modules, so match, test and exclude will not help in this case.

Comment: @Adi: I think that you are right, which is why I asked the question in the first place… :)  nose seems to looks for *functions* that start with `test_` etc. in the package init code…

Answer (score 0):

I think the nose-exclude plugin may help.  If you install this plugin and then run:

```
    nosetests --exclude-dir B
```

It may work for you.  I have the same problem and have achieved some passable results.  Now my next issue is that the `exclude-dir` doesn't seem to be a usable option when creating a nosetests config file.